# How to detect whether word file is modified or not using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document in .net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, office-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document in .net.
I am using below code to open the file.

```
    Dim openedDoc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document = ActivePRADocument.Application.Documents.Open(FileName:=sProvantisPrint, [ReadOnly]:=False)
```

It opens the file correctly but even if I dont change anything on the file it prompts to save the document when the file is closed.

In the event DocumentBeforeClose of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application it checks the Saved property of Word document as shown:

```
    If Not closingDocument.WordDocument.Saved Then
         ' 120020: "Do you want to save file ‘{0}’?"
        If AddInMessageBox.Show(120020, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
         MessageBoxIcon.Warning, closingDocument.WordDocument.Name) = DialogResult.Yes Then
               closingDocument.WordDocument.Save()
     Else
              closingDocument.WordDocument.Saved = True
      End If
   End If
```

But even if i dont change anything on the document when i close the word this 'Saved' property is set to false. And it prompts to save the document.

Is there any way so that I can find out whether the document is actually changed or not? And prompt only when it is changed.

Comment: That property acts like a flag (and it's a `Get/Set` property). You need to set it to `true` if the Document has already been saved (or you don't want the automatic prompt). Otherwise it'll be set to the default `false`.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. It worked.